# Subclass foo extends JTable. TableModelListener.getSource returns JTable not foo

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

Hopefully a simple question but I am struggling with inheritance.

The ultimate goal is to detect when a cell is changed in a JTable and then run an action that involves getting an extra specific property associated with the table.

I have a class that extends JTable, so that I can add some extra properties to the table. The point of extending JTable is so that when a TableModelListener is activated I can get at the extra properties.

```
public class dataTable extends JTable implements TableModelListener{

private final PowerpointTable extraProperty;

public dataTable(String[][] tableArray, String[] colNames, PowerpointTable extraProperty) {
    super(tableArray, colNames);
    this.extraProperty= extraProperty;

    }

    public PowerpointTable  getExtraProperty() {
        return this.extraProperty;
    }
}
```

I would then like to treat this class like a JTable and in another class create the table and add an table listener that fires when the cells are changed.

```
public secondClass {

     public secondClass() {}

     public void createTable() {
         dataTable newdataTable= new dataTable(tableArray, columnNames, currentTable);
         newdataTable.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

         @Override
         public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
               PowerpointTable pptT = tme.getSource().getExtraProperty;
         });
}
```

however getSource only returns a JTable which cannot be cast to a dataTable.

Please let me know how I can access this property or if there is a better way to implement this functionality.

Comment: `PowerpointTable pptT = ((DataTable)tme.getSource()).getExtraProperty;` should work as long as you are certain that `newdataTable` is a `DataTable`. Be careful with the parentheses.  There may be a more elegant way.

Comment: That was the way I tried first but it throws a java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: I don't know why it is return `JTable` but i checked the source code `TableModelEvent`. And `getSource()` method seems to return `TableModel` which is not a parent of `JTable`. Maybe you can share with us more information about how this event fire.

Comment: @rdonuk I have done my best to explain the usage for the event. Please let me know if I can clarify further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it,

as rdonuk pointed out, getSource returns a TableModel,

I therefore changed the first class to extend a DefaultTableModel and added the extra property.

```
public class TryingTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

public TryingTableModel(PowerpointTable pptRef, Object[][] os, Object[] os1) {
    super(os, os1);
    this.pptRef = pptRef;
}

private final PowerpointTable pptRef;

public PowerpointTable getPPTTable() {
    return this.pptRef;
}

public String testAccess() {
    return "it worked";
}
```

The JTable is now initialised in the second class

```
TryingTableModel tableModel = new TryingTableModel(currentTable, tableArray, columnNames);
tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
    TryingTableModel tableModel = (TryingTableModel) tme.getSource();
    System.out.println(tableModel.testAccess());
    }
});

JTable newJTable = new JTable(tableModel);
```